# How to count web-site previews in Whatsapp etc?

Tags: javascript, php, web, whatsapp, preview

The problem is:
1.  The message, which I want to send to a list of recipients in WhatsApp, contains the link to a web-page. 
2.  The number of recipients is going to be more than a hundred (typically, a group of students). 
3.  I need to keep records how many recipients received this message by counting the number of page previews or in some other way. I don’t need to count IPs, or collect their telephone numbers or names. I need to get just a number of people received it. 
As I understand, WhatsApp client application only once generates the web-page preview, and then puts it into a cache in order to show it when necessary. That means there is no way to count the web-pages previews on a server side. Am I correct? 
Is there another way to count the receipts of the message?

Answer (score 2):

I see two different approaches to check who has received your link.

### Use WhatsApp Read Receipts

You can easily see who has read your message in WhatsApp group chats by the blue check marks or the message info as described in [their faq](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/28000015/?category=5245250)

### Checking the access log of your web server to see how many clients have accessed your site to generate a rich link preview

However your title says you want to count how many times the website has been previewed on different devices.
I assume you have access to the access log of the web server hosting the website.

Then you can check how often WhatsApp clients created the [rich link preview](https://richpreview.com/) of your site by counting the number of client whose user-agent contained WhatsApp.

If I send a link to my website in a WhatsApp chat I can see entries like this in my web servers access log:

```
domain.tld 0 123.123.123.123 - - [01/Sep/2018:09:35:10 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5928 "-" "WhatsApp/2.18.163 A"
```

You said you want to know on how many devices the preview has been displayed. You can try to distinguish between the clients by their ip addresses, but that solution isn't perfect since the ip of a device can change frequently.

### Count how many times the preview of the website has been generated in php without access to the web server logs

You can also determine whether a user visits your site a web browser or if it is just WhatsApp generating the preview in php.

It is done by checking whether the user agent contains "WhatApp" or not.

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'WhatsApp') !== false) {
    increasePreviewCount();
}
```

The problem of distinguishing between different clients remains with this approach.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I haven't been clear from the beginning, sorry. What I want to do is to form a link with request string, like: http://example.com?coupon=197234&id=972345 and I need to be able to record the number of previews of that code. I do not have access to log files, as the site is on hosting servers.

Comment: Of course, there is a way of doing smth like this: https://hackerone.com/reports/309367
but there might be another way to do so

Comment: Okay, I have updated my answer and described how to count the times the preview has been generated in php. The problem of telling apart different devices remains.

Comment: Thanks again. The thing is that it works once and does not go further, as if php server keeps generated preview in cache. I was trying to disable php cache, but it did not work in preview either.